# Reformat column names in a csv with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

### Question

How do I reformat an unknown CSV column name according to a formula or subroutine (e.g. rename column `" Arbitrary Column Name "` to `"Arbitrary Column Name"` by running a trim or regex or something) while maintaining data?

### Goal

I'm trying to more or less sanitize columns (the names) in a hand-produced (or at least hand-edited) csv file that needs to be processed by an existing PowerShell script. In this specific case, the columns have spaces that would be removed by a call to `[String]::Trim()`, or which could be ignored with an appropriate regex, but I can't figure a way to call or use those techniques when importing or processing a CSV.

### Short Background

Most files and columns have historically been entered into the CSV properly, but recently a few columns were being dropped during processing; I determined it was because the files contained a space (e.g., `Select-Object` was being told to get `"RFC"`, but `Import-CSV` retrieved `"RFC "`, so no matchy-matchy). Telling the customer to enter it correctly by hand (though preferred and much simpler) is not an option in this case.

### Options considered

I could manually process the text of the file, but that is a messy and error prone way to re-invent the wheel. I wonder if there's a syntax with `Select-Object` that would allow a softer match for column names, but I can't find that info.

The closest I have come conceptually is using a calculated property in the call to `Select-Object` to rename the column, but I can only find ways to rename a known column to another known column. So, this would require enumerating the columns and matching them exactly (preferred) or a softer match (like comparing after trimming or matching via regex as a fallback) with expected column names, then creating a collection of name mappings to use in constructing calculated properties from that information to select into a new object.

That seems like it would work, but more it's work than I'd prefer, and I can't help but hope that there's a simpler way I haven't been able to find via Google. Maybe I should try Bing?

Answer (score 0):

### Sample File

Let's say you have a `file.csv` like this:

```
" RFC "
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

### Code

Now try to run the following:

```
$CSV = Get-Content file.csv -First 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$FixedHeaders = $CSV.PSObject.Properties.Name.Trim(' ')
Import-Csv file.csv -Header $FixedHeaders |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 -Property RFC
```

### Output

You will get this output:

```
RFC
---
1  
2  
3
```

### Explanation

First we use `Get-Content` with parameter `-First 2` to get the first two lines. Piping to `ConvertFrom-Csv` will allow us to access the headers with `PSObject.Properties.Name`. Use `Import-Csv` with the `-Header` parameter to use the trimmed headers. Pipe to `Select-Object` and use `-Skip 1` to skip the original headers.

Comment: This looks like about what I was hoping for (the closest I could imagine to clean) - I'll test and select if it works like it seems to (though I just noticed something that makes me wonder). Thanks! ---- I'll also post the less clean but more generic solution that I came up with if it seems like it adds anything to the discussion

Comment: I was just walking through it mentally and playing devil's advocate. I'm wondering: what if someone's really mean or careless and puts carriage returns in one or more header names? I don't think `Get-Content` will parse through that properly...(?)

Comment: `Get-Content file.csv -First 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv` will probably fail if you have carriage returns in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about comparisons in terms of efficiency, but I think this is a little more hardened, and imports the CSV only once. You might be able to use @lahell's approach and `Get-Content -raw`, but this was done and it works, so I'm gonna leave it to the community to determine which is better...

```
#import the CSV
$rawCSV = Import-Csv $Path

#get actual header names and map to their reformatted versions
$CSVColumns = @{}
$rawCSV | 
    Get-Member | 
    Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Foreach-Object {

        #add a mapping to the original from a trimmed and whitespace-reduced version of the original
        $CSVColumns.Add(($_.Trim() -replace '(\s)\s+', '$1'), "$_")
    }

#Create the array of names and calculated properties to pass to Select-Object
$SelectColumns = @()
$CSVColumns.GetEnumerator() |
    Foreach-Object {
        $SelectColumns += {
            if ($CSVColumns.values -contains $_.key) {$_.key}
            else { @{Name = $_.key; Expression = $CSVColumns[$_.key]} }
        }
    }

$FormattedCSV = $rawCSV | 
    Select-Object $SelectColumns
```

This was hand-copied to a computer where I don't have the rights to run it, so there might be an error - I tried to copy it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use gocsv https://github.com/DataFoxCo/gocsv to see the headers of the csv, you can then rename the headers, behead the file, swap columns, join, merge, any number of transformations you want